# How to say "gaslighting" in professional writing

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I am writing an application in which I complain that every time I point out to the cooks or their supervisor that the meal is not up to the mark,and actually show them how it is, they  say that no body else complains, only I complain. However, whenever I ask my colleagues about this, they tell me that what I am saying is valid, and they also point it out all the time.

So this is a habit of this staff to gaslight women employees like this. We have put up with this for years.

Therefore, I'll really appreciate if someone can help in this. I need a synonym of gas-lighting which conveys the intent properly.

Comment: "Dismissive of your and others' concerns," "unprofessional in receiving and responding to feedback", and "inappropriate response to customer concerns" are examples of ways you might approach this.

Comment: That isn't what the word "gaslighting" typically means, so even in non-professional settings that term would be misleading. Gaslighting is a severe form of psychological abuse intentionally targeted to make someone question their own sanity, rendering them isolated and easy to control; it doesn't really apply here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would agree with Rmac’s suggested phrasings (“Dismissive of your and others' concerns," "unprofessional in receiving and responding to feedback"), which are more appropriate in a professional context (an application) where “gaslighting” does not seem an appropriate tone to take, as it is fairly aggressive and accusatory. In professional work contexts it’s best to describe interpersonal conflicts in tactful language. I also agree with Alphabet that “gaslighting” is not just disagreement, it is more specifically about denying something that you believe in order to get you to question whether you believe it or are crazy or are confused. Doesn’t seem their disagreement here is using the gaslighting tactic here.

Comment: Maybe copy the suggested phrasing into this answer (with credit of course) because comments can disappear or be deleted.

Comment: In AmE contexts, **gaslighting** has come to mean "misleading people again and again to get them to doubt their own common sense and believe your self-serving view of things".  It is losing much of the original sense of "getting a person to doubt their own sanity".  Now the goal is to get them to think they are misinformed or have been lied to repeatedly by others.